# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/lo g4j/LogManager

Tags: java, log4j

Estou tentando iniciar um arquivo jar e assim que executo, recebo esse erro! Vocês podem me ajudar?

> ```
> C:\Unky\Web\BloodStrikeServer-master>mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
> 'mvn' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
> ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
>
> C:\Unky\Web\BloodStrikeServer-master>java -jar target/lobbyplayer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
> -fat.jar
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/lo
> g4j/LogManager
>         at com.bloodstrike.lobbyserver.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:17)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
>
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         ... 1 more
>
> C:\Unky\Web\BloodStrikeServer-master>pause Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
> ```

Arquivo main:

```java
package com.bloodstrike.lobbyserver;


import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import io.vertx.core.logging.Logger;
import io.vertx.core.logging.LoggerFactory;

import com.bloodstrike.lobbyserver.manager.NetworkManager;

import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.net.NetClient;
import io.vertx.core.net.NetServer;
import io.vertx.core.net.NetSocket;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        logger.info("===============================================================================");
        logger.info("BloodStrike Lobby Server");
        logger.info("Créditos: ExtremsX");
        logger.info("Versão: 0.1 Beta");
        logger.info("===============================================================================");

        logger.info("Carregando Configurações");
        Config.loadConfig();

        logger.info("Iniciando NetworkManager");
        NetworkManager.getInstance();

            Vertx.vertx().setTimer(1000, id -> {
                    try {
                        startClientDebug();
                        logger.info("Iniciando DUMPER");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.error("Falha ao iniciar o DUMPER");
                    }
            });


        logger.info("Iniciando NetworkServer");
        NetworkServer.getInstance();
    }

    private static void startClientDebug() throws Exception {
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
        int port = Integer.parseInt("4000");
        String host = "0.0.0.0";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("./network.dump");

        NetServer server = Vertx.vertx().createNetServer();
        server.connectHandler(handler -> {
            NetClient client = Vertx.vertx().createNetClient();
            log.error("Nova conexão recebida de " + handler.remoteAddress());

            client.connect(port, host, res -> {
                if (!res.succeeded()) {
                    log.error("Erro ao se conectar ao servidor", res.cause());
                    try { fos.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
                    return;
                }
                log.error("Erro ao se conectar ao servidor", res.cause());

                NetSocket socket = res.result();
                // Do cliente para o servidor
                handler.handler(buffer -> {
                    try { 
                        fos.write("\n\nClient -> Servidor\n".getBytes()); 
                        fos.write(buffer.getBytes());
                    } catch (Exception e) { }
                    socket.write(buffer);
                });

                // Do servidor para o cliente
                socket.handler(buffer -> {
                    try { 
                        fos.write("\n\nServidor -> Client\n".getBytes());
                        fos.write(buffer.getBytes());
                    } catch (Exception e) { }
                    handler.write(buffer);
                });
            });
        });
        server.listen(3999, res -> {
            if (!res.succeeded())
                return;
            log.info("Servidor DUMPER iniciado na porta 3999");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Se no seu arquivo `main`, você colocar um `//` antes de qualquer chamada, uso ou importação do `Logger`, ele funciona?

Comment: Já tentou trocar as chamadas ao log4j por `System.out.println`?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> C:\Unky\Web\BloodStrikeServer-master>mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
> 'mvn' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
> ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
> ```

O maven não está devidamente instalado. Basta insalar o maven e certificar-se que a pasta `bin` dele está na variável `%PATH%`.

Quanto a esse comando:

```
java -jar target/lobbyplayer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar
```

Faltou colocar o log4j no classpath. Deveria ser assim:

```
java -cp log4j.jar -jar target/lobbyplayer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar
```

Talvez você precise também colocar vários outros JARs, seria assim:

```
java -cp pasta1/jar1.jar;pasta2/jar2.jar -jar target/lobbyplayer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar
```

Utilize `;` para separar o nome de um JAR do outro no classpath. Você pode acabar precisando de um monte de JARs.

Comment: Já fiz isso e continua a mesma coisa

Comment: já nem sei mais oq fazer, tentei tantas coisas e nunca deu certo, ficava sempre no mesmo erro, só agora fui apelar para a ajuda de alguem

Comment: @JúlioSousa O JAR do log4j está em qual pasta?

Comment: java -cp classpaths/log4j-api-2.6.2.jar;classpaths/log4j-core-2.6.2.jar -jar target/lobbyplayer-0.0.1-

SNAPSHOT-fat.jar pause depois de alterar, criei a pasta e pus os jars]

Comment: E esses dois JARs estão na pasta `C:\Unky\Web\BloodStrikeServer-master\classpaths`, né? É `classpaths` no plural mesmo?

Comment: Antes de mais nada, alem de usar os necessarios para o app, necessita de uma outra api do log4j?

Comment: Se fosse esse o problema, ele provavelmente daria um erro diferente.

Comment: Sim. pus no plural propositalmente, mas eu pus a pasta no plural e as cp tambem

Comment: Bem, então não sei o que é. Deve ser alguma coisa boba, mas não sei.

Comment: Já tentei de tudo, trocar de log4j para slf4j, já tentei mudar algo na manifest.mf, mas sempre fica no mesmo erro. Não consigo entender o por que disso :P