# Sobre: Erros do Vertx

Tags: java

Estava testando minha aplicação, e quando executei, recebi o seguinte erro:

```
===============================================================================
BloodStrike Lobby Server
Créditos: ExtremsX
Versão: 0.1 Beta
===============================================================================
Carregando Configurações
Erro ao carregar as cofiguraçõesjava.lang.NullPointerException
Iniciando NetworkManager
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.(ILjava/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory;)V
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.(VertxImpl.java:129)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.(VertxImpl.java:119)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.(VertxImpl.java:115)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:34)
    at io.vertx.core.Vertx.vertx(Vertx.java:80)
    at com.bloodstrike.lobbyserver.Main.startClientDebug(Main.java:48)
    at com.bloodstrike.lobbyserver.Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

O que é esse erro, como resolver, porque é chamado?

Comment: Significa que você tem um JAR do netty no seu classpath/modulepath que é de uma versão incompatível com o do vertx. Você pode baixar a versão correta no https://netty.io/

Comment: Esta pergunta é um desdobramento de uma pergunta anterior (não é duplicata): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318616/132

Comment: Victor, vamos mover essa discussão para um chat, preciso mesmo de tua ajuda nesse projeto

Comment: Pra você ter noção, nem uso netty nesse projeto e esta bugando... apenas uso o vertx

Comment: Então, aparentemente o vertx usa o netty obrigatoriamente (não sei porque, mas usa). Logo, não dá para você usar o vertx sem usar o netty também. Aparentemente há algum JAR do netty no seu classpath, mas não é o correto.